# "Warning: Could not delete locked file" when running InstallShield Wizard

Tags: linux, installshield

I am trying to run an uninstall script that is based on the InstallShield Wizard.
but at the end of the installation I get:

"The InstallShield Wizard has successfully uninstalled BlaTest.
Choose Finish to exit the wizard.

Press 3 to Finish or 4 to Redisplay [3]
WARNING: could not delete locked file /opt/BlaTest/test/log"

This happened on 2 different Linux machines: OEL6.3 and RHEL5.7 (I did not check it on other versions).

also, log is a folder.

I checked all the permissions and they are OK.
I tried running it from a different folder (outside of the program I am trying to delete): and it did not help.

is anyone familiar with this problem and could help me find out what is the problem ?

Thanks.

Comment: What is the permission on this file?

Comment: just to make sure that they were ok, I gave it full permissions (777) - it did not help.